# How to change files name of django InMemoryUploadedFile before upload to S3 without models?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

**Environments**

Django==3.24

DRF==3.11

boto3==1.16

django-storages==1.10

---

I want to change files name before upload to s3 without saving in DB(model).

I tried like this.

```py
# in Post request
files = request.FILES.getlist('files')

res = []

for file in files:
    random_car = ''.join(random.SystemRandom().choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for _ in range(8))
    ext = file.name.split('.')[-1]
    file_name = f'{random_car}.{ext}'

    # -------- try start ---------
    # I want to change file name to file_name
    # This code throws an error.
    # FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '8.jpeg' -> 'kVuepnuR.jpeg'
    os.rename(file.name, file_name)
    # -------- try end ---------

    file_path_within_bucket = os.path.join(
        file_directory_within_bucket,
        file.name
    )

    default_storage.save(file_path_within_bucket, file)
    file_url = default_storage.url(file_path_within_bucket)

    res.append(file_url)
```

How can I change the name if InMemoryUploadedFile?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve it and share this.

```py
random_car = ''.join(random.SystemRandom().choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for _ in range(8))
ext = file.name.split('.')[-1]
file_name = f'{random_car}.{ext}'

file_path_within_bucket = os.path.join(
    file_directory_within_bucket,
    f"{file_name}"
)
```

istead of

```py
random_car = ''.join(random.SystemRandom().choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for _ in range(8))
ext = file.name.split('.')[-1]
file_name = f'{random_car}.{ext}'


file_path_within_bucket = os.path.join(
    file_directory_within_bucket,
    file.name
)
```